# Can't use PrincipalContext in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a login page for my project in the company using the Active Directory accounts of my company. I'm trying to use the `PrincipalContext()` but tried to import it and error won't go away.

Is there any way to use `PrincipalContext` on c#?
Tutorials and other source code in my company uses vb.net.

[image]

Comment: `Project > Add Reference > Assemblies > System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement > OK`

Comment: You need to add a reference to the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` dll. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

It may not be installed on your system. For this

```
 1. Right Click Project. 
 2. Manage NuGetPackages.
 3. Search for System.DirectoryServices.I
 4. Install System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
```